# What can I do with callCC that cannot be done with cont?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

I'm really really struggling with understanding callCC. I get the power of Continuations and I've been using the concept in some of my projects to create cool concepts. But never have I needed to use something with greater capabilities than `cont :: ((a->r)->r)-> Cont r a`.

After using it, it makes a lot of sense why they call the Cont Monad the mother of all monads, YET, I don't get when would I need to use `callCC`, and that's exactly my question.

Comment: How have you used `Cont`?  When you say you haven't needed to use something more powerful than `cont`, does that mean you haven't used `reset` or `shift` either?

Comment: I haven't used `reset` or `shift`. I've used it to define an eembedded language that can be suspended until a given action is resolved by another process, and then it resumes with the given "continuation". Maybe I give the impression of having a lot of experience with Cont Monad, but not that much really, I just really want to understand callCC

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`callCC` gives you "early return" semantics, but in a monadic context.

Say you wanted to `doOne`, and if that returns `True`, you immediately stop, otherwise you go on to `doTwo` and `doThree`:

```hs
doOne :: Cont r Bool
doTwo :: Cont r ()
doThree :: Cont r ()

doThings :: Cont r ()
doThings = do
    one <- doOne
    if one
        then pure ()
        else do
            doTwo
            doThree
```

See that `if` branching there? One branch is not that bad, could be dealt with, but imagine there are multiple such points where you just want to bail? This gets very ugly very quickly.

With `callCC` you can have "early return": you bail at the branching point and don't have to nest the rest of the computation:

```hs
doThings = callCC \ret -> do
    one <- doOne
    when one $ ret ()
    doTwo
    doThree
```

Much more pleasant to read!

More importantly, since `ret` here is not a special syntax (like `return` in C-like languages), but just a value like any other, you can pass it to other functions too! And those functions can then perform what's called "non-local return" - i.e. they can "stop" the `doThings` computation, even from multiple nested calls deep. For example, I could factor out checking of the `doOne`'s result into a separate function `checkOne` like this:

```hs
checkOne ret = do
    one <- doOne
    when one $ ret ()

doThings = callCC \ret -> do
    checkOne ret
    doTwo
    doThree
```

Comment: I get it! and `b` is basically just a wildcard so that you can chain more continuations inside callCC. Anyway, once `ret` is applied, the continuation produced by call cc will "return" whatever was put in `ret`. That's pretty convoluted, yet pretty smart, yet extremely powerful I see not a lot of places where using such power is not like killing a fly with a nuke

Comment: @caeus Glad I could help. If you liked my answer, would you consider accepting it?